# How to install Unity 3D in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: unity3d

I have used Blender and Unity 3D in Windows 8. Recently I have started using Ubuntu 17.04. Can anyone tell me the procedure to install Unity 3D Game Engine. 
Thank You

Answer (score 4):

You can download `.deb` file from this [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/). After that type the following:

> sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
>   sudo apt-get install -f
>   sudo dpkg -i filename.deb

Comment: Official installers do not come with a. `.deb` file now. For some reason this does not work as expected.